# jQuery Datatable sorting for Column with Mixed Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm implementing Sorting using jQuery Datatables. In second column we have mixed datatype (text/string, amount with currency symbol). The second column does not sort properly although numbers sort but cells with text/string do not change position. I want to move text to last when sorting is active for the second column. In simple words, the cells with number should be higher in hierarchy /priority while sorting.

The table and sorting can be checked below by clicking on "Run Snippet"

Thank you!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>jQuery(document).ready( function () {jQuery("#postsummary").DataTable({paging: false, "searching": false, columnDefs: [ { type: "num-fmt", targets : 1 } ], });} );</script>

<table
  id="postsummary"
  class="dataTable no-footer"
  aria-describedby="postsummary_info"
>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th
        class="sorting"
        tabindex="0"
        aria-controls="postsummary"
        rowspan="1"
        colspan="1"
        aria-label="Name of Program: activate to sort column ascending"
        style="width: 573.075px"
      >
        Name of Program
      </th>
      <th
        class="sorting sorting_asc"
        tabindex="0"
        aria-controls="postsummary"
        rowspan="1"
        colspan="1"
        aria-label="Amount: activate to sort column descending"
        style="width: 95.9125px"
        aria-sort="ascending"
      >
        Amount
      </th>
      <th
        class="sorting"
        tabindex="0"
        aria-controls="postsummary"
        rowspan="1"
        colspan="1"
        aria-label="Type: activate to sort column ascending"
        style="width: 100.863px"
      >
        Type
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="">
        Testing 1
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">varying</td>
      <td class="">Compensation</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="">
        Testing 2
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">$50,000</td>
      <td class="">Grant</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="">
        Testing 3
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">$500,000</td>
      <td class="">Grant</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="">
        Testing 4
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">varying</td>
      <td class="">Grant</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="">
        Testing 5
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">varying</td>
      <td class="">Grant</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="">
        Testing 6
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">$3,500</td>
      <td class="">Grant</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't force non-numeric data to be numeric :-).

If you want to sort, you probably want to write yourself a custom sort algorithm:

https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/